# How to use correctly segue with a Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

My application use a different master detail, its consist in an initial ViewController with a tableView, but when the user click the Add button in the navigation controller I need send an object using the follow function:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AddDGV"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailView:object];
    }
}
```

The code works fine when the destination is another ViewController, but my application was designed to have TabBarController instead a ViewController. This TabBar have 2 tabs, each one with a different Navigation Controller, and the first one is the target to the identifier "AddDGV". I created the .m/.h files and associated the class in the storyboard, and set the instance variable "DetailView" as ID.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
```

The problem is the compiler don't know this variable, because the command `[segue destinationViewController]` contains the view controller whose contents should be displayed at the end of the segue. As the end of the segue is a TabBarController, the function doesn't work.

Someone knows how fix it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecast the output of

```
[segue destinationViewController]
```

as follows

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AddDGV"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [(YourDestinationViewController *)[segue destinationViewController] setDetailView:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler does not accept this typecast directly, but if I create a variable of the type from destination before, works fine. Thanks by your help, I'll try finish this app now.